# NodeJS Get Specific Value from Parsed JSON results

Tags: node.js, json, parsing

I'd like to get the numeric value of the object 'add_ele' from the following result using NodeJS, can somebody please show me how?

```
[
  { code: 'switch', value: true },
  { code: 'countdown_1', value: 0 },
  { code: 'add_ele', value: 151800 },
  { code: 'cur_current', value: 0 },
  { code: 'cur_power', value: 0 },
  { code: 'cur_voltage', value: 2140 },
  { code: 'test_bit', value: 0 },
  { code: 'voltage_coe', value: 0 },
  { code: 'electric_coe', value: 0 },
  { code: 'power_coe', value: 0 },
  { code: 'electricity_coe', value: 0 },
  { code: 'fault', value: 0 },
  { code: 'relay_status', value: 'last' },
  { code: 'child_lock', value: false }
]
```

I have not been able to fins a way to do this so far

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code.

Method 1:

```
const arr = [
  { code: 'switch', value: true },
  { code: 'countdown_1', value: 0 },
  { code: 'add_ele', value: 151800 },
  { code: 'cur_current', value: 0 },
  { code: 'cur_power', value: 0 },
  { code: 'cur_voltage', value: 2140 },
  { code: 'test_bit', value: 0 },
  { code: 'voltage_coe', value: 0 },
  { code: 'electric_coe', value: 0 },
  { code: 'power_coe', value: 0 },
  { code: 'electricity_coe', value: 0 },
  { code: 'fault', value: 0 },
  { code: 'relay_status', value: 'last' },
  { code: 'child_lock', value: false }
]

let result

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i].code === 'add_ele') {
    result = arr[i].value;
    break;
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Method 2:

```
const arr = [
  { code: 'switch', value: true },
  { code: 'countdown_1', value: 0 },
  { code: 'add_ele', value: 151800 },
  { code: 'cur_current', value: 0 },
  { code: 'cur_power', value: 0 },
  { code: 'cur_voltage', value: 2140 },
  { code: 'test_bit', value: 0 },
  { code: 'voltage_coe', value: 0 },
  { code: 'electric_coe', value: 0 },
  { code: 'power_coe', value: 0 },
  { code: 'electricity_coe', value: 0 },
  { code: 'fault', value: 0 },
  { code: 'relay_status', value: 'last' },
  { code: 'child_lock', value: false }
];

const resObj = arr.find(item => item.code === 'add_ele');
const result = resObj.value;

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [
  { code: 'switch', value: true },
  { code: 'countdown_1', value: 0 },
  { code: 'add_ele', value: 151800 },
  { code: 'cur_current', value: 0 },
  { code: 'cur_power', value: 0 },
  { code: 'cur_voltage', value: 2140 },
  { code: 'test_bit', value: 0 },
  { code: 'voltage_coe', value: 0 },
  { code: 'electric_coe', value: 0 },
  { code: 'power_coe', value: 0 },
  { code: 'electricity_coe', value: 0 },
  { code: 'fault', value: 0 },
  { code: 'relay_status', value: 'last' },
  { code: 'child_lock', value: false }
]

const result = arr.filter(item => item.code === 'add_ele')[0].value
console.log(result)
```